# Button click working only if i click right hand side of button

Tags: html, css, button, click

A button name in my html has two text, when I click the second text only the button click is working. Need to make the entire button clickable and show pointer cursor when I mouse over.

```
<div class="d-flex">
  <button (click)="myfunction()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  *ngIf="currentPath!= 
  '/users/userlist'">Car List</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain better, your problem is difficult to reproduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple: `cursor: pointer;`

Just like this:

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.d-flex .btn {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex">
  <button (click)="myfunction()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  *ngIf="currentPath!= 
  '/users/userlist'">Car List</button>
</div>
```

See more at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor .

Comment: Not exactly, some near by div is overlapping with this button that's why, i tried putting high value for z-index still not working fully!Thanks!

Comment: yes worked finally, it was the problem of z-index.i put 99999!

Comment: insteed of messing with high z-index values you could just add pointer-events:none; to the div overlapping and problem solved... asuming this div does not have any king of interaction with the user.

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez Oh Okay! Thanks for the great suggestion !